# Will a vector move if I don't call push_back?

Tags: c++11, memory-management

I'm working with a function that takes as input an array of structures of the form

```
struct Info
{
  const char* something;
  // more stuff
};
```

Since I didn't want to worry about cleaning up the memory in the `char*`, my thinking was that I'd

1. Create a `std::vector<std::string>` of all the `something`
2. loop over the vector and create the `Info` structures using `std::vector::c_str()`
3. feed the structures to the function.

That way the vector owns all the strings and I don't have to worry about memory management. My only concern is that the vector could decide to move the strings in memory at some point, which would invalidate the pointers I'm getting from `c_str()`.

So my question: assuming I don't add anything to the vector, can I count on the pointers to stay where they are? As a bonus, can I combine steps 1 and 2 into a single loop assuming I call `reserve` before so that the vector doesn't have to move?

Comment: Yes, as long as you don't touch the vector, it won't spontaneously change on you; not even when the clock strikes twelve. Yes, the vector is guaranteed to not reallocate or invalidate existing elements on `push_back` as long as its capacity is not exceeded; so the `reserve` approach would work.

Comment: I'd accept this as an answer if it had a citation.

Comment: **[vector.modifiers]/1** Causes reallocation if the new size is greater than the old capacity. If no reallocation happens, all the iterators and references before the insertion point remain valid.